# Update in sql server 2012 only time part of a date

Tags: date, sql-update, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to perform an update in a sql server 2012 database but only of the time part?

I have this data:

```
id | date
1  | 2013-09-01 15:25:58.526
2  | 2013-05-10 12:12:34.345
3  | 2013-05-10 11:23:33.234
4  | 2013-04-07 15:34:01.345
```

And i want to change all the times to 00:00:00.000... how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE 
SET date = CAST(
            FLOOR( 
                CAST( date AS FLOAT ) 
            ) AS DATETIME
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
UPDATE Table1 SET [date] = CAST([date] as DATE)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85660/2)

Another option would be something like

```
UPDATE Table1 SET [date] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date]));
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85660/1)